# How to say one of every five people properly

Tags: verb, conjunction

How can I say *one of every five people*?

Ein von jede fünf Menschen.

Comment: Jeder fünfte Mensch.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer:

> Jeder Fünfte.

Another variation:

> Einer von Fünfen.

Answer (score 3):

Direct translation:

> Jeder fünfte Mensch

A variant:

> Ein Fünftel aller Menschen

Another possibility, which is correct as well, but to my eye seems a bit less common:

> Einer unter fünf Menschen

Comment: 'Einer unter 5 Menschen' sounds wrong. Better were 'Einer von 5 Menschenv

Comment: Actually, it is correct, but not very common. But google "einer unter 100" to see some examples.

Comment: Du hast recht. Duden http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unter_darunter_abwaerts_tiefer Abschnitt 8. Trotzdem würde ich bei beliebigen 5 Menschen nicht an eine Gruppenzugehörigkeit denken.